# VBS for selecting dynamic filename

Tags: excel, vbscript

I know there are a lot of posts which say they are new to VBS, but honestly, I have never written VBS code before....
What I am trying to automate is a report and I have managed to cobble together the following:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\pierre\Desktop\Test folder\16 10 19 Spreadsheet.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "macro1"
xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Obviously it just opens an excel workbook at a specific location, runs a macro and ends, but what I dont understand is how to account for a dymanic filename in the code eg the date is going to change, but nothing else?
Is there a wildcard variable that can be used?

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the date to a variable and use that in your filename:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Dim formattedDate
formattedDate = Right(datepart("yy", Now), 2) & " " & DatePart("m", Now) & " " & DatePart("d", Now)
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\pierre\Desktop\Test folder\" & formattedDate & " Spreadsheet.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "macro1"
xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Here we use function [datepart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ee97hz(v=vs.90).aspx) to get pieces of the current date `Now`. We also make use of function `Right()` which will get the right-most number of characters specified for the string in the first parameter. All of that is concatenated together using the `&` concatenation operator. Then with that formattedDate we just concatenate it right into the filename.

Comment: @JNeville I'd make shure the Excel file exists before trying to open a dynamically generated file name. A different approach would be to handover the file name as an argument to the vbscript.

Comment: I agree that some hardening and refactoring is needed here, but that's not in the scope of the question. The question is how to get a dynamic filename based on the date. This is one way to go about that. Passing the filename as a parameter to this code redefined as a function only pushes the need to dynamically determine the filename to some code outside the function, which is the code I've added to answer the question. One could also make the user type in the file name, which is terrible if it's based on current date, or pop up a file dialog and make them dig and click.